# Orthogonal projections on ellipsoids in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

In TikZ, I want to draw the orthogonal projection from a point to a (rotated and shifted) ellipse. As a particular example, I would want to draw the shortest line from the point in the picture to the ellipse and preferably mark the point on the ellipse as well:

[image]

I have succeeded doing this with a circle (since the point is just given by the intersection with the circle and the line through the point itself and the center of the circle). But with the ellipse, I can't seem to get it to work in TikZ.

The example code for the above picture goes as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
{(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[shift={(-0.875,0)},rotate=25] \boundellipse{0,0}{1}{3};%left

\node at (0,4)[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the maths required is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194000/1274254

Answer (score 4):

I suggest TikZ + gradient descent

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\boundellipse}[3]% center, xdim, ydim
    {(#1) ellipse (#2 and #3)}

\makeatletter
\xdef\sx{-0.875} % shift x
\xdef\sy{0} % shift y
\xdef\ra{1} % radius a
\xdef\rb{3} % radius b
\xdef\ro{25} % rotation
\pgfpointxy{0}{4}
\xdef\Px{\the\pgf@x}\xdef\Py{\the\pgf@y}

% let \ang ("angle") be a free variable and run gradient descent
\def\ang{234} % choose your favorite initial value
\foreach\iterationcounter in{1,...,20}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(-5,-3)rectangle(1,5);
        \draw[shift={(-0.875,0)},rotate=25] \boundellipse{0,0}{1}{3};
        \node at (0,4)[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]{};
        % evaluate Ellipse(\ang)
        \pgfpointxy{\sx + \rb*cos(\ang)*sin(\ro) + \ra*sin(\ang)*cos(\ro)}
                    {\sy - \rb*cos(\ang)*cos(\ro) + \ra*sin(\ang)*sin(\ro)}
        \xdef\Qx{\the\pgf@x}\xdef\Qy{\the\pgf@y}
        \draw(\Qx,\Qy)circle(.1);
        % evaluate diff vector to target point
        \xdef\Dx{\the\dimexpr\Px-\Qx}
        \xdef\Dy{\the\dimexpr\Py-\Qy}
        \draw[red,->](\Qx,\Qy)--+(\Dx,\Dy);
        % evaluate tangent line = d Ellipse(\ang) / d\ang 
        \pgfpointxy{- \rb*sin(\ang)*sin(\ro) + \ra*cos(\ang)*cos(\ro)}
                    {+ \rb*sin(\ang)*cos(\ro) + \ra*cos(\ang)*sin(\ro)}
        \xdef\Tx{\the\pgf@x}
        \xdef\Ty{\the\pgf@y}
        \draw[blue,->](\Qx,\Qy)--+(\Tx,\Ty);
        % inner product
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Inn{\Dx*\Tx + \Dy*\Ty}
        % rescale inner product
        \pgfmathsetmacro\inn{\Inn / sqrt(\Tx*\Tx+\Ty*\Ty)}
        \message{^^J thinbold: \inn ^^J}
        % update angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ang{\ang + \inn/10} % /10 is the step length
        \xdef\ang{\ang}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### The math problem and the algorithmic approach

As @Thruston suggests math is needed to solve the problem. Anyway this leads to a not trivial (quartic) equation which is hard to solve in the analytic way (let have a look at either [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22961669) or [Point-to-ellipse and point-to-ellipsoid distance equation analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318875654_Point-to-ellipse_and_point-to-ellipsoid_distance_equation_analysis)).
So the idea is to solve that an equation numerically. On https://wet-robots.ghost.io/simple-method-for-distance-to-ellipse/ I found a geometric and stable algorithm which find the point (orthogonal projection) on the ellipse by minimizing the distance from the original point.

### The algorithm

The following steps and the image will suggest the idea.

1. Connect *O* and *P* in oder to get *A_start* (this allows to run the algorithm "on the right side" of the ellipse).
2. Draw a circle (blue) and get the midpoint of the two intersections with the blue circle and the ellipse.
3. Use the midpoint to draw a new smaller circle (purple) and iterate the process (i.e. red, orange, pink,...)

[image]

### The code

The code needs the packages `tikz` and `tkz-euclide` and in particular `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` for the intersection points. I use `tkz-euclide` because I feel good with the commands. Anyway you can get the same result in pure tikz.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% INITIAL DATA %
% the arbitrary point P
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){P}
% the center of the ellipse
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
% use rotate=angle to set the desired orientation
\path[draw,name path=theellipse,rotate=20] (O) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](P)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)

% STARTING POINT OF ALGORITHM %
\path[name path=OP] (O)--(P);
\path[name intersections={of=OP and theellipse,by={Aone}}];
% comment/erase if need next three code lines
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](Aone){$A_{\textrm{start}}$}
\tkzDrawCircle[help lines](P,Aone)
\tkzDrawPoints(Aone)

% ALGORITHM TO FIND THE ORTHOGONAL PROJECTION %
% set up a different number of steps if needed
% (algorithm converges relatively fast)
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
{
% define a circle with center P through Aone
% (Astart for the first step)
\tkzDefCircle[radius](P,Aone)
\tkzGetLength{dPAone}
\path[name path=circle] (P) circle (\dPAone pt);

% find intersections of circle with ellipse (Aone, Atwo)
\path[name intersections={of=circle and theellipse,by={Atwo,Aone}}];

% find a "proper" midpoint of Aone -- Atwo on the ellipse
\tkzDefMidPoint(Aone,Atwo)\tkzGetPoint{Aone}
\path[name path=PAone] (P)--(Aone);
\path[name intersections={of=PAone and theellipse,by={Aone}}];
}


% GET AND PRINT OUT THE DISTANCE
\tkzDrawPoints(O,P,Aone)
\tkzDrawSegment[red](P,Aone)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, you can do this very simply in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using the `solve` macro and a suitable helper function.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path e; pair p; numeric k;
    e = fullcircle xscaled 233 yscaled 144 rotated 10;
    p = 160 dir 142;

    vardef acute(expr t) =
        direction t of e dotprod (p - point t of e) > 0
    enddef;

    k = solve acute(0, 4);

    drawarrow p -- point k of e withcolor red;
    draw e; 
    dotlabel.top(btex $p$ etex, p);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you can compile it with `lualatex`.

### Notes

- `solve` is explained on pages 176-177 of [the Metafont book](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/abcde.html).
- The idea is that you define macro `foo` such that `foo(x)` is either `true` or `false`.  Then you call `solve foo(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are values such that `foo(a)` is true and `foo(b)` is false.  `solve` uses a binary search to find the edge value between `a` and `b`.
- In this case I have defined a macro called `acute` that uses the `dotprod` operator to tell us whether the tangent at point `t` of the ellipse makes an acute angle with the line from `p` to point `t` of the ellipse.
- `solve` finds the point at which the angle is no longer acute, which is therefore the point at which the line to `p` is orthogonal to the tangent, and is therefore the closest to `p`.
- Some skill and judgment is required to pick the correct initial values for different positions of `p`.

As you can see my explanation is rather longer than the code...