# How to pin an ellipse with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to pin from the perimeter an ellipse built with a command \draw by specifying a particular point (like `south`, `north west`, etc) or an angle for example, as is possible with a `node`. The best I have been able to do so far with my various attempts is to pin the center of the ellipse, but not its perimeter.

I have looked for a solution but have not found one. I tried to name the ellipse via the `name path` option, but it does not work. I have the following error message : `Package pgf Error: No shape named '...' is known.`.

So, how can I pin an ellipse to get a result like this?

[image]

In general, is it possible to convert simple shapes such as rectangles, circles and ellipses drawn with the `\draw` command to `shape` in the Tikz sense?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rotate around={-45:(0.8,0.4)}, name path=test](0.8,0.4) ellipse [x radius=2.5mm , y radius= 5.5mm];%
    \node[pin = {[]45:Test}] at (test.south) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also relevant:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569799/15036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `ellipse` node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ellipse, draw, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=11mm, rotate around={-45:(0.8,0.4)}, pin=north:Test] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are surely more elaborate ways to do this, but you can add nodes (or other stuff) as markings to any path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position .25 with {
        \node[pin={[]45:Test}, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};
    }
    }]

    \draw[postaction={decorate}, rotate around={-45:(0.8,0.4)}] (0.8,0.4) 
        ellipse[x radius=2.5mm, y radius=5.5mm];
        
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,-2) .. controls (1,0) and  (2,-3) .. (4,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basic geometic forms such as rectangle, circle or ellipse are already available as shapes for nodes, the more elaborate ones via the `shapes.geometric` library. For such shapes, it would be better to use a node with a pin.

Comment: With this solution `pin` no longer work as expected, it does't rotate around the ellipse if you ought to change the angle.

Comment: This is true. You would need to adjust both the position on the path and the angle of the pin. I added this suggestion, because the OP asked for a general solution to convert paths to nodes, so I though adding a solution that works for whatever path would be nice. But sure, If you just want to add a pin to a node shaped like an ellipsis, this is not quite the way to go.